# Weighted grouped histogram in a single non-overlapping plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

Given a `DataFrame` with observation weights and groups, how can one construct a grouped weighted histogram in matplotlib? I'm looking for something like this:

[image: Source: https://twitter.com/Econ_Marshall/status/1220847559461175297/photo/2]

Data could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'by' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
     'val' : [4., 3., 2., 1., np.nan],
     'w' : [10., 8., np.nan, 5., 7.]}     
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I can get separate histograms using the pandas plotting `by` arg, e.g.:

```
df.hist('val', by='by')
```

[image]

or

```
df.groupby('by').plot.hist('val')
```

[image]

But pandas plotting doesn't support either [adding weights](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9540) to that, or AFAICT plotting the histograms on the same plot.

[This guide](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/plots/matplotlib-histogram-python-examples/) shows how to plot them on the same plot, but the series overlap, and also don't use common bins. It also doesn't use observation weights, though it looks like they could be added.
[image]

Comment: It might be easier to extract the data and weights from the array and create the histograms using `np.hist` before plotting them with matplotlib directly. Numpy offers finer control over the histogram itself and matplotlib finer control of the plotting